# Islamic point about husband refuses to sex

Tags: hadith, sex

Are there any hadeeths about a husband refusing sex due to fatigue or sleepiness even if wife is constantly demanding sex?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hadith in which the Prophet ﷺ was informed that Abdullah Ibn 'Amr had neglected his wife's marital rights. The Prophet ﷺ reminded him that "your wife has a right over you."

> Al-Bukhârî reported that 'Abd Allâh ibn 'Amr ibn Al-'Âs ﷺ said, "The Messenger of Allâh صلَّى الله عليه وسلَّم said to me: "O, 'Abd Allâh, have I not been informed that you fast by day and watch by night in prayer? "That is true, O Messenger of Allâh," I replied. "He  ﷺ said, "Do not! Fast and eat, pray and sleep, for your body has a claim on you, your eyes have a claim on you and your wife has a claim on you. " "

Legally, if the wife claims that the husband does not satisfy her sufficiently in this case, the legal threshold is once every four days. Here, the husband is legally obliged to satisfy his wife according to this threshold as a minimum.

Imam al Ghazali states in his Ihya 'Ulum ad din that "A man should make love to his wife every four nights... although he should make love to her more or less than that, depending on how much she needs to remain chaste and without need since it is obligatory for a husband to enable her to remain chaste.

> In a weak hadith reported in Musnad Abu Y'ala, the Prophet ﷺ is reported to have said, "If any of you has sex with his wife, let him be faithful to her. If he reaches his pleasure before she does, he should not hurry her until she also reaches her pleasure. Although the hadith is weak, the meaning is sound, as mentioned by the scholars.